# please suggest about a basic example

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, struts2

any expert tell me where i find a basic example of Srtuts2+Spring+Hibernate

Answer (score 2):

I can help you with Hibernate.

Hibernate

1. design a database, or take something off the shelf.
2. download eclipse+ [hibernate tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)
3. read instructions on how to setup hibernate, you can autogenerate your mapping + config files directly from the database.
4. try some queries out in the HQL and Criteria editor (Eclipse)
5. fire up Hyperion in your test app with code like this:

   ```
   public class SessionManager implements HibernateSessionManager {
       static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
       static {
       try {       
           sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
       } catch (Throwable e) {
           System.err.println("Error in creating SessionFactory object." 
           + e.getMessage());
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
       }
       }
   ```

SessionManager.sessionFactory.OpenSession() will open a connection that you can run a query with.

once you get hibernate down then layer spring on top, then struts on top of that. trying to do it all at once is a lesson in frustration.

Answer (score 1):

[Struts2+spring+hibernate tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)

Answer (score 0):

This example is available on the [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html) site.